# Delete Xcode and download again instead of making update?

Tags: xcode, xcode12

I'm using Xcode 12.5 (12E262) on a MacBook Air with macOS Big Sur 11.5.1 (20G80).

App Store says, there's a new update for Xcode.

When trying to start the update, I get a message that the update cannot get started because there isn't enough disk space.

Can I simply delete my current version of Xcode and then download the version from the App Store? Because this will allow me to have enough disk space.

Or will this delete preferences or something else?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes, you can remove the current Xcode and install a new version from Mac App Store. However, you will probably encounter the same error for insufficient disk space, as it requires more than 40GB free space to expand and install Xcode.

To solve your problem, you can download Xcode from [Apple Developer Portal](https://developer.apple.com/download/) and extract the XIP file in an **external drive** (of course you still need sufficient space). Then, move the extracted Xcode app back to your Mac's Applications folder.

Also, before you try the method above, you can use a software called [DevCleaner](https://apps.apple.com/us/app/devcleaner-for-xcode/id1388020431?mt=12), which can clean the unused simulator files, logs and derived data in your Mac.

Last, if you are brave enough, you can use this script to wipe clean your Xcode traces in your Mac (I personally use this to free up spaces when installing a new version):

```
killall Xcode
xcrun -k
xcodebuild -alltargets clean
rm -rf "$(getconf DARWIN_USER_CACHE_DIR)/org.llvm.clang/ModuleCache"
rm -rf "$(getconf DARWIN_USER_CACHE_DIR)/org.llvm.clang.$(whoami)/ModuleCache"
sudo rm -rf /Applications/Xcode.app
rm -rf ~/Library/Caches/com.apple.dt.Xcode
rm -rf ~/Library/Developer
rm -rf ~/Library/MobileDevice
rm -rf ~/Library/Preferences/com.apple.dt.Xcode.plist
rm -rf ~/Library/Preferences/com.apple.dt.xcodebuild.plist
sudo rm -rf /Library/Preferences/com.apple.dt.Xcode.plist
sudo rm -rf /System/Library/Receipts/com.apple.pkg.XcodeExtensionSupport.bom
sudo rm -rf /System/Library/Receipts/com.apple.pkg.XcodeExtensionSupport.plist
sudo rm -rf /System/Library/Receipts/com.apple.pkg.XcodeSystemResources.bom
sudo rm -rf /System/Library/Receipts/com.apple.pkg.XcodeSystemResources.plist
sudo rm -rf /private/var/db/receipts/com.apple.pkg.Xcode.bom
```

save the file as `uninstall_xcode.sh` and run it from Terminal. Admin rights required.

Comment: If I remove the current Xcode and install a new version from the App Store, will any preferences, simulators or similar get lost?

Comment: The preferences & simulators are not saved in `/Applications` folder (it's in `~/Library` folder), so they don't get affected. Note: Using my script will wipe the preferences and simulators.

Comment: Go with care with the MobileDevice line as it will probably erase all your installed Provisioning Profiles and similar stuff. Maybe it's something you can't/don't want to  mess with (so that's a line I typically comment).

Comment: Provisioning Profiles can be re-downloaded with a single click in Xcode. No worries.

Comment: The project I work with is such a BIG BEAST regarding provisioning profiles (literally dozens of them, schemes, targets, certificates, etc...) that the last thing I would ever wanted to do is letting Xcode perform its magic and then having to lose precious time fine-tuning and checking everything is working as before (sometimes Xcode breaks things). I wish I had found a similar warning in the past as the one I just posted above... It still might be useful for someone anyway

Comment: manual profiles (not those automatically generated by Xcode) can also be downloaded again using "Download Manual Profiles" function in Xcode. For the certificates and keys, it's stored in Keychain Access; for the custom Targets you mentioned, it's stored in your Xcode workspace (`*.xcworkspace`), therefore it's not related to the deletion of the above directories.

Comment: If I delete the Xcode in my mac, other users in the mac also not able to build the app. Becuse the Xcode is commonly for all the users. But the project got differs. If I remove and installs again, does this affect the other users and shall i need to add the setup for the project again for all the other users. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70243458/xcrun-simctl-list-failed-to-show-the-list-dvtassertions-assertion-failure-in

Comment: Xcode is the IDE software. After you re-install the Xcode, your project does not require to be re-configured, except for the provisioning profiles.

Comment: I needed to use "sudo" for "rm -rf /Applications/Xcode.app".  I ran into a lot of permission denied errors without sudo.

Comment: @FeFiFoFu you're right. I made changes to the script above, thanks.