# xcrun simctl list failed to show the list (DVTAssertions: ASSERTION FAILURE in /Library/Caches/com.apple.xbs/)

Tags: ios, xcode, ios-simulator, simulator

While trying to runt the xcrun command it shows the below error and failed to show the list of the simulator.

xcrun: error: unable to find utility "simctl", not a developer tool or in PATH

Note: In my machine has the simctl in the path

> /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin/simctl

but while running the command

> xcrun --find simctl

> xcrun simctl list

it shows the below error.

```
2021-12-06 15:06:27.787 xcodebuild[10591:373217] [MT] DVTAssertions: ASSERTION FAILURE in /Library/Caches/com.apple.xbs/Sources/IDEXcode3ProjectSupport/IDEXcode3ProjectSupport-18132/Xcode3Core/LegacyProjects/Frameworks/DevToolsCore/DevToolsCore/Foundation/Specifications/XCSpecification.m:1504
Details:  propertyList should be an instance inheriting from TSPropertyListDictionary, but it is nil
Object:   <XCSpecificationProxy: 0x7fef67ca5540>
Method:   -loadedSpecification
Thread:   <NSThread: 0x7fef67f07d80>{number = 1, name = main}
Hints: 

Backtrace:
  0   -[DVTAssertionHandler handleFailureInMethod:object:fileName:lineNumber:assertionSignature:messageFormat:arguments:] (in DVTFoundation)
  1   _DVTAssertionHandler (in DVTFoundation)
  2   _DVTAssertionFailureHandler (in DVTFoundation)
  3   -[XCSpecificationProxy loadedSpecification] (in DevToolsCore)
  4   +[XCSpecification specificationForIdentifier:inDomain:] (in DevToolsCore)
  5   -[XCCommandLineToolSpecification_FileTypeAcceptanceInfo initWithPropertyListDictionary:forToolSpecification:] (in DevToolsCore)
  6   -[XCCommandLineToolSpecification_FileTypeAcceptanceInfo initWithFileTypeIdentifier:forToolSpecification:] (in DevToolsCore)
  7   -[XCCommandLineToolSpecification initWithPropertyListDictionary:inDomain:] (in DevToolsCore)
  8   -[XCCompilerSpecification initWithPropertyListDictionary:inDomain:] (in DevToolsCore)
  9   -[PBXCompilerSpecificationGcc initWithPropertyListDictionary:inDomain:] (in DevToolsCore)
 10   -[PBXCompilerSpecificationGcc3_1 initWithPropertyListDictionary:inDomain:] (in DevToolsCore)
 11   -[XCSpecificationProxy loadedSpecification] (in DevToolsCore)
 12   +[XCSpecification specificationForIdentifier:inDomain:] (in DevToolsCore)
 13   -[XCSpecificationProxy loadedSpecification] (in DevToolsCore)
 14   +[XCSpecification specificationForIdentifier:inDomain:] (in DevToolsCore)
 15   -[XCSpecificationProxy loadedSpecification] (in DevToolsCore)
 16   +[XCSpecification specificationForIdentifier:inDomain:] (in DevToolsCore)
 17   -[XCSpecificationProxy loadedSpecification] (in DevToolsCore)
 18   __58-[XCSDKPackage createCommandLineToolSpecificationRegistry]_block_invoke (in DevToolsCore)
 19   __79+[XCSpecification enumerateSpecificationsInDomain:includingDefault:usingBlock:]_block_invoke (in DevToolsCore)
 20   __202+[XCSpecification _recursivelyEnumerateSpecificationsInStartDomain:currentDomain:registryNameOrNil:specificationIdentifierOrNil:alreadyEnumeratedDomains:alreadyEnumeratedIdentifiers:stopPtr:usingBlock:]_block_invoke (in DevToolsCore)
 21   __202+[XCSpecification _recursivelyEnumerateSpecificationsInStartDomain:currentDomain:registryNameOrNil:specificationIdentifierOrNil:alreadyEnumeratedDomains:alreadyEnumeratedIdentifiers:stopPtr:usingBlock:]_block_invoke_2 (in DevToolsCore)
 22   __NSDICTIONARY_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_BLOCK__ (in CoreFoundation)
 23   -[__NSDictionaryM enumerateKeysAndObjectsWithOptions:usingBlock:] (in CoreFoundation)
 24   __202+[XCSpecification _recursivelyEnumerateSpecificationsInStartDomain:currentDomain:registryNameOrNil:specificationIdentifierOrNil:alreadyEnumeratedDomains:alreadyEnumeratedIdentifiers:stopPtr:usingBlock:]_block_invoke.55 (in DevToolsCore)
 25   +[XCSpecification _recursivelyEnumerateSpecificationsInStartDomain:currentDomain:registryNameOrNil:specificationIdentifierOrNil:alreadyEnumeratedDomains:alreadyEnumeratedIdentifiers:stopPtr:usingBlock:] (in DevToolsCore)
 26   +[XCSpecification _enumerateAllSpecificationsInDomain:registryNameOrNil:specificationIdentifierOrNil:includingDefault:usingBlock:] (in DevToolsCore)
 27   +[XCSpecification enumerateSpecificationsInDomain:includingDefault:usingBlock:] (in DevToolsCore)
 28   -[XCSDKPackage createCommandLineToolSpecificationRegistry] (in DevToolsCore)
 29   -[XCPlatformSpecification loadSpecificationsAndPlugins] (in DevToolsCore)
 30   +[XCPlatformSpecification loadAllPlatforms] (in DevToolsCore)
 31   XCInitializeCoreIfNeeded (in DevToolsCore)
 32   +[Xcode3CoreInitializer ide_initializeWithOptions:error:] (in Xcode3Core)
 33   _IDEInitializeBuildSystem (in IDEFoundation)
 34   IDEInitialize (in IDEFoundation)
 35   -[Xcode3CommandLineBuildTool run] (in Xcode3Core)
 36   main (in xcodebuild)
 37   start (in libdyld.dylib)
sh: line 1: 10593 Abort trap: 6           /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin/xcodebuild -sdk /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk -find simctl 2> /dev/null
xcrun: error: sh -c '/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin/xcodebuild -sdk /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk -find simctl 2> /dev/null' failed with exit code 34304: (null) (errno=Invalid argument)
xcrun: error: unable to find utility "simctl", not a developer tool or in PATH
```

Answer (score 0):

I've faced this issue in Xcode 13.3 beta, I re-install stable Xcode 13.2.1 version and it solved my error.

https://developer.apple.com/download/all/